# Odd behaviour when using word boundaries [[:<:]] and [[:>]]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, database

My task is to create a blacklist for entries in different strings. I am checking for the entries right in database using `MySQL`.

You probably know about word boundary marks in `MySQL`:
`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` which correspond to `\b` in default regexps.

Something goes wrong when there are `regexp special characters` and `word boundary marks` in a string.

**But those characters are escaped by double backslashes!**

Just run this query

```
SELECT 
"test()" REGEXP "[[:<:]]test\\(\\)[[:>:]]", 
"test()" REGEXP "test\\(\\)", 
"test"   REGEXP "[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]",
"test"   REGEXP "test" ;
```

And you will get

```
0 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

Instead of expected

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

Could someone, please, explain how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can do that nicely in MySQL. As there are no lookarounds (and no way to negate `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`?).

Depending on how you define word boundary (especially when non-word characters are involved, eg `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`) you can in some cases use expression like:

```
(^|[[:space:]])test\(\)($|[[:space:]])
```

Answer (score 3):

The first fails because the last word boundary can't match a word boundary: a closing parenthesis and the end of the string isn't a word boundary position. To quote the definition given of the [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):
"*A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters.*"

As a side note, it won't work for another language either.

Comment: Thank you for the description of the problem, now I get it. Voting up.